# Accessing resources in a specific resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

I want to have several resource dictionaries in my application and access a resource defined in a particular resource dictionary. Is this possible? According to what I have read, the looking up for a particular key is a native process and we don't have a control over it. In fact, I will have the same key for several resources in different resource dictionaries. If I go with the current procedure only the one which is closest in the hierarchy tree will be used. Instead I want to tell the application explicitly to use a resource in a specific resource dictionary. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [answer](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/124621/281641.aspx) should help you with your problem

Comment: Hi Greco, thanks for further enlighting me on the same. I found the link giving me more details than I expected. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy that I could help you out with your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my question was idiotic? (Please let me know if the following answer is an expression of the same quality once again). The answer is simple. What should be done is to define the resource dictionaries the way you want in separate xaml files and add them under the source property when needed (of course you can do this via C# code). Then it won't be a problem whether you have the same key or not, only the referred xaml will be used as the provider of resources.